# What does security detail mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shield

In the TV show *The Shield*, Vic has got two autistic children that need special education which demands a bit more money than Vic's salary can afford, so that he goes to his captain and asks for more overtime, more shift and a security detail.

I understand overtime and extra shifts will bring in additional income to Vic, but what does "security detail" mean in the context of a detective within a police station?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Security Detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_detail) is a kind of 'personal guard' - like the Secret Service guys who surround the President (especially in movies, there seems to be a trope that no President can have too many Secret Service guys - the more there are, the more likely for something to go wrong;)

I don't recall Vic's reasoning for mentioning Security Detail; I have a vague recollection it may later have to do with some armoured trucks... but it's too many years since I saw it.

Comment: A police detective can be a personal guard and get paid by the police station for doing it? I guess it is perhaps to guard a political figure rather than anyone else.

Comment: idk about the US, but in the UK I know serving officers can do additional duty on such as movie location security when they take place in public, even using official Police cars/bikes, so long as it is on their usual day off. They are paid by the production, not the Police force.